# Vim register becomes random values in gvim

Tags: gvim, register

Given the php code at the end, I add it to my gVim register with `"ky`.

Everything is fine. After some time, when I use it, the vim register looks like this:

```
jjjjjjjjjjjjj/^Mkkkkkkkkkkjjjpjjjjjjjjjjjjj
```

(it's much longer but you get the idea)

What is happening here?

**original code added to register**

```php
  $query = "
     update contacts
     SET last_contact = :lc,
     email = :email,
     AND user_id = :user_id";

  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

  $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email);
  $stmt->bindValue(":lc", $lc);
  $stmt->bindValue(":user_id", $user_id);

  $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It's really too bad that Vim doesn't come with some kind of comprehensive documentation that we could follow to learn it properly. Because of that we must count on sheer (bad) luck to discover random features. Bad Vim. Bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have hit `qk` by inadvertance. Vim would have then started to record a macro in register `k` that contains the key you type.

Comment: O, so do macros save into the registers then?

Comment: Yes indeed :-) `:help q` for more information. If the answer adress your problem feel free to accept it using the v button. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @Vinn see `:help q` on that. The first note pretty much covers your issue. BTW, a lot of tricks exploit macro=register, like editing macros in your editor etc.

Comment: I just realized I pretty much duplicated Vivian's comment. Sorry for that. I must have still been asleep while I wrote it :-)